# Calculating voltage given other voltages in a circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

I am self studying circuit-analysis, and got the following question wrong.

[image]

I thought the answer was c, but it is actually d.  Could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

It wanted the entire circuit to have overall 0 voltage so if we have 2 voltages in 2 different direction they are fighting against eachother so we get the diffrance so we have

$$12+V=10+8$$
so solving we get
$$V=10+8-12$$
$$V=6$$

Comment: If you go all the way around any circuit loop, the sum of the voltage drops is zero. (A rise is a negative drop.)